# How to find and display a specific value in a C# array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I have made a program in C# that reads a file of numbers, turns them into an array, and uses a bubble sort to display them in numerical order and I'm trying to make it so after the program prints the array it finds and prints the 10th value in the array after the bubble sort I'm new to C# and can't find anything on it through googling and was wondering if there's a simple way to do this.

Below is the part of my code that does the sort and output.

```
 public void Bubble()
        {
            string[] road1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\legom\OneDrive\Documents\Road_1_256.txt");
            int[] a = Array.ConvertAll(road1, int.Parse);
            int t;
            for (int p = 0; p <= a.Length - 2; p++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= a.Length - 2; i++)
                {
                    if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
                    {
                        t = a[i + 1];
                        a[i + 1] = a[i];
                        a[i] = t;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (int aa in a)
                Console.Write(aa + " "); public void Bubble()
        {
            string[] road1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\legom\OneDrive\Documents\Algorithams assignment\Road_1_256.txt");
            int[] a = Array.ConvertAll(road1, int.Parse);
            int t;
            for (int p = 0; p <= a.Length - 2; p++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= a.Length - 2; i++)
                {
                    if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
                    {
                        t = a[i + 1];
                        a[i + 1] = a[i];
                        a[i] = t;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (int aa in a)
                Console.Write(aa + " ");
```

Comment: You "made a program" that *sorts* an array, but can't write code to extract a particular element (which is a necessary part of sorting an array)?

Comment: Your code, as is, does not compile.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is another one of _can you please solve my homework for me_.

Comment: Give an array `a` and an int index `i`, describe what `a[i]` does.

Comment: Hint: to address `i`th item you use `a[i]`, so to address `10`-th item you should put...

Answer (score 1):

If execution speed isn't extremely important, you can use LINQ to do much of this work for you:

```
using System.LINQ;

...

var array = yourArrayHere;
int elementIndex = 9;
var tenthElementAfterSorting = array.OrderBy(e => e).ElementAt(elementIndex);
```

You can put something else within OrderBy(), if you want to use different sorting criteria. Also, OrderBy() is a stable sort, meaning if two items have the same sorting criteria their original relative ordering will be preserved. Without this sorting stability, getting the Nth element may return different results between different calls unexpectedly.

Also worth noting is OrderBy() uses a stable form of QuickSort, which is a lot faster than BubbleSort.

Comment: `Without this sorting stability, getting the Nth element may return different results between different calls unexpectedly.` In the context of integers, that is a moot point.

Comment: Yeah, in this particular case with filenames, you shouldn't ever have two identically named files. But I suggested the option to change the sorting criteria, so it felt worth mentioning, since the sorting criteria could change to something where sort stability could be a factor.